# Not show AdControl in windows silverlight 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

i work fine with keytest but my Ad unit ID not show ads. When create Ad units in my account, it generate Ad units Id include 6 characters. but Ad units Id of other account or keytest have 8 characters for Ad Units Id? anyone help me? thanks

Answer (score 0):

first you need to drag add mediator from toolbox to your xaml code ,
then goto solution explorer and right click on project and select ad reference,

then new windows will appear select extension > and check windows phone ad mediator or something option like that.

after above two process goto again in solution explorer and and right click on your project add click on add >> Add connected service, and then select add mediator there.

and new wizard will start to configure your ad unit and id.

after all that , setup add mediator (which will be added by you from tool box) padding and place it where you want .

for more details and codes go to this microsoft [documentaion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn864355.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: for doing all that first you need to install microsoft ad sdk from this link https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb4b3020-9b56-4e81-a314-e40cff00fb52  or install respective sdk which ad network you use e.d if you use adduplex ad duplex will provide you a ad sdk for visual studio